# JQuery looping not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am working on the JQuery loop on the textbox such that whenever the classname="xyz" then it needs to put datetime control there else the textbox needs to work as a regular textbox where I have set validations. I am having trouble looping through using Jquery .each. Can someone let me know if I am missing something.

```
<script>
    $(".xyz").each(function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass('xyz')) {
            $(".xyz").datepicker();
        }})
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" CssClass="xyz"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Is this the same order that appears in your code?

Comment: @maccenttura :yes. Is anything wrong

Comment: Just `$(".xyz").datepicker();` should suffice, right now you're looping all elements with class 'xyz', then checking if it has the class 'xyz' and then applying a datepicker on all elements with the class 'xyz'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the second class selector.  Inside the loop you are already targeting each element with the "xyz" class.  So just use the "this" keyword to perform your operation.

```
<script>
    $(".xyz").each(function () {
      $(this).datepicker();
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" CssClass="xyz"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I am still unable to loop through the textbox with xyz class and attach datetime picker to it. it applies to the first element only. in code behind i have: txt.Attributes["CssClass"] = "xyz";

Comment: Run this before the above and you'll find out how many elements are being selected at the time your JavaScript runs.  alert($(".xyz").length);  Sounds like you have a bigger problem then what you've posted here.

Comment: I have added alert, it returns 3, as I have 3 textboxes. As per the requirement the textbox needs to behave as both textbox which accepts phone number when phno. is selected from dropdown else if the user selects date, the textbox needs to act like a datetimepicker.

Comment: That seems like a terrible spec, but I'd suggest you use dedicated "phone number" and "datepicker" controls for each and just hide/show them based on the drop down selected value.

Answer (score 1):

A jquery selector (such as `$(".xyz")`) returns a set of elements. When you append a method to a selector, the method is applies to all elements in the set.

So instead of a loop, you just need

```
$(".xyz").datepicker();
```

JQuery will do the looping for you. It will

1. Obtain a list of all elements with a class of `xyz`
2. On each element in the list, run the `datepicker()` method.

The only time you need `each` is when you want to supply your own function, which is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, thought it might be helpful for someone in future. Here's the solution: 
Within the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="abc" runat="server" CssClass="f-c"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ee").each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('ee')) {
                //alert($(".ee").length)
                $(this).datepicker();
            }

        })
    });
</script>
```

code behind:

```
abc.CssClass = abc.CssClass + "ee";
```

Using this the textbox acts as both regular textbox and datetime picker.